# How to pass params parameter through link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Controller

```
class FeedEntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = FeedEntry.search(params[:is_star])
    @feed_entries = @search.page(params[:page])
    @app_keys = AppKey.all
  end
end
```

In View - feed_entries/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Stared", {:controller => "feed_entries", :action => "index", :is_star => false } %>
```

feed_entries table contain `is_star:boolean` attribute. So, I just want to pass the parameter is_star == true into the `params[:is_star]`.

But the above code is not working. Please some one help me.

If, I click the `Stared` link. I am getting error like below in the browser:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys!' for "false":String
```

Comment: did you try quoting false? - i.e. `:is_star => "false"`

Comment: ya getting same error

Comment: you should probably include the stacktrace for your error - my guess, it is coming from inside the `FeedEntry#search` method?

Comment: Could you post the routes associated with the FeedEntries controller?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your FeedEntry#search method expects an argument that responds to #stringify_keys! methods, so I assume you should pass a Hash :

```
@search = FeedEntry.search(is_star: params[:is_star])
```

BTW link_to with 'controller' and 'action' options is old and verbose syntax, you should use a resourceful style:

```
link_to 'Stared', feed_entries_path
```

read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to